# Does playing with a different user active on the Switch create a different file?

Tags: nintendo-switch, super-smash-bros-ultimate

In Smash Ultimate (just like all other Smash games) you have only one save file, so you can't just load another if somebody else wants to play without messing with their progression. I've tried looking into this on the Nintendo website, but that has not been very helpful. I have heard that a function like this exists for certain other games who function like this (Breath of the Wild), but I can't find anything about this for Smash Ultimate.

Note that I am not asking about the Nintendo Account that is used to shop for games and download DLC, I'm asking about the user account that you make when first starting a new Switch.

Comment: How many Users do you have on your switch? When you launch Smash bros (or another game) does it have you choose a profile first?

Comment: Note: Smash Ultimate has 3 save files for the World of Light adventure mode.

Comment: From what i can gather/research, Nintendo and PS4 seem to have the same separation between accounts. In other words, on PS4, your save data is tied to each account on the system. If i wanted to have a fresh start at BFV/I didn't want someone ruining my K/D, I would just log them in to a separate account. I might not be understanding your question correctly either, so feel free to set me straight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with almost every game on the switch, your save data is tied to your user account. Each user profile on the Switch has their own save data.

However in addition to this, with the new Switch Online program, Smash Ultimate supports [Cloud Saves](https://www.nintendo.com/switch/online-service/save-data-cloud/) which will backup your data on the Nintendo account your switch account is linked with. This means that you’ll be able to pull save data down from the cloud onto another switch if you so desired.

So your save data is both linked to the local User Profile on the Switch and (if you use Cloud Saves) to the Nintendo account the User Profile is linked with.

Comment: “As with almost every game”: are there any exceptions to this rule?

Comment: @StevenM.Vascellaro I know that Hulu for example doesn’t have you choose a user before opening (and so doesn’t show in your profile with hours played like other games). That’s the only one I know of, but it’s enough to keep me from making the generalization.

Comment: After managing to actually try it out for myself I discovered that yes, with a different User Account you create an entirely different save file. So far, the only thing I found to be shared beyond the confines of a User Account are Miis.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this and all save data for this game appears to be tied to the account you play with.

I started up with a second account and everything was running as if the game had been started for the first time.  I re-unlocked an Eevee spirit for Let's Go Eevee save, the fighter roster was back to the initial fighters, the World of Light had 3 open save slots, Challenge mode and all other stats had no values.

Comment: So it's tied to the Nintendo Account that is currently logged in and not the user who is currently active, then?

Comment: Save data is tied to the account you pick when starting up the game.

Comment: Nintendo Account or user account?

Comment: User account, the one who is actually playing